# Google Datastore one to many relationship in java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Looking at the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities) I couldn't find any good explanation how to structure data, when there is one to many relationship. The problem is that single query takes quite  lot of time, so it's not a good solution to make multiple queries.

Let's assume following structure:

```
   Entity
   Key(String hash) value(String) ...other values

   User
   Key(String hash) Entity Key(String hash)
```

Now if I can query all User's Entities hash keys and for each key make a query to get actual values, but it's not an option since making as many queries as many Entites are assigned to user are too much time consuming.

How should I structure my data, or how to make a single query to retrieve all User's data?

Answer (score 0):

Given the following scenario -

- UserEntity
- NotesEntity

One user has zero or more Notes (one to many)

One approach is to set UserEntity as the Parent for each Notes Entity

- UserEntity - Key, Name, Email
- NotesEntity - Key, Parent Key (User), Notes Date, Notes Description

Now to retrieve All or a Page of Notes for a given user, you could just run one Ancestor query as below:

```
SELECT * FROM NotesEntity WHERE __key__ HAS ANCESTOR a_user_key
```

Comment: But how it would look like using datastore? Also I have to assume that NotesEntity can have multiple parents.

Comment: Please take a look at the documentation - https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#ancestor_paths. If a NotesEntity can have multiple parents (Users), then it becomes a many-to-many relation, not one-to-many.

Comment: You are right, my bad. So should I use multi level parent key?